# Problem with Nearest vertex and Shortest Path function in Leaflet

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, pgrouting

I am a new Leaflet user and I have challenge to get shortest path by pgRouting, GeoServer and Leaflet as a front end application. I followed this tutorial
[pgRouting + GeoServer + Leaflet JS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gfdQmFkVmE&list=PLaOYwKHOUv7Z2KyZNTXhLhwYm-XeEs34H) as a reference, I published layers on GeoServer and created SQL view for each function (nearest vertex, shortest path) successfully as explained in the videos.

the store name: routing
layer name: nearest_vertex
layer name: shortest_path

The problem with me in the last step, in Leaflet JS file I don't know what is the cause of the problem and how to solve it.

```
ERROR: Parsing error: Unexpected character '`'  var url = `${geoserverUrl}/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=routing:nearest_vertex&outputformat=application/json&viewparams=x:${
```

Leafletjs script

```
var geoserverUrl = "http://localhost:8080/geoserver";
var selectedPoint = null;

var source = null;
var target = null;

// initialize our map
var map = L.map("map", {
    center: [30.00073607, 31.40345240],
    zoom: 16 //set the zoom level
});

//add openstreet map baselayer to the map
var OpenStreetMap = L.tileLayer(
    "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
    {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution:
            '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }
).addTo(map);

// empty geojson layer for the shortes path result
var pathLayer = L.geoJSON(null);

// draggable marker for starting point. Note the marker is initialized with an initial starting position
var sourceMarker = L.marker([30.00572470, 31.38871190], {
    draggable: true
})
    .on("dragend", function(e) {
        selectedPoint = e.target.getLatLng();
        getVertex(selectedPoint);
        getRoute();
    })
    .addTo(map);

// draggbale marker for destination point.Note the marker is initialized with an initial destination positon
var targetMarker = L.marker([30.00476310, 31.39870580], {
    draggable: true
})
    .on("dragend", function(e) {
        selectedPoint = e.target.getLatLng();
        getVertex(selectedPoint);
        getRoute();
    })
    .addTo(map);

// function to get nearest vertex to the passed point
function getVertex(selectedPoint) {
    var url = `${geoserverUrl}/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=routing:nearest_vertex&outputformat=application/json&viewparams=x:${
        selectedPoint.lng
    };y:${selectedPoint.lat};`;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            loadVertex(
                data,
                selectedPoint.toString() === sourceMarker.getLatLng().toString()
            );
        }
    });
}

// function to update the source and target nodes as returned from geoserver for later querying
function loadVertex(response, isSource) {
    var features = response.features;
    map.removeLayer(pathLayer);
    if (isSource) {
        source = features[0].properties.id;
    } else {
        target = features[0].properties.id;
    }
}

// function to get the shortest path from the give source and target nodes
function getRoute() {
    var url = `${geoserverUrl}/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=routing:shortest_path&outputformat=application/json&viewparams=source:${source};target:${target};`;

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        map.removeLayer(pathLayer);
        pathLayer = L.geoJSON(data);
        map.addLayer(pathLayer);
    });
}

getVertex(sourceMarker.getLatLng());
getVertex(targetMarker.getLatLng());
getRoute();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width">
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title> Routing App</title>

    <!-- link the css files -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <div class="navbar-icon-container">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-icon pull-right visible-xs" id="nav-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg white"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> Routing App</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <!-- the map will go inside this div below -->
        <div id="map"></div>
        <!-- link to the js files -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, #container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

/*this is important to give the map a height*/
#map {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this last screen shot is unreadable. Please, post relevant JS code and error messages as text.

Comment: edited and added js code

Comment: Don't post pictures of errors please - it remains unreadable

Comment: ok thank you, it's possible to ask the same question without post picture?

Comment: What environment you are trying to run this code? Back tick string syntax should work in all browsers, except IE11.

Comment: Brackets, and Google Chrome as a live debug

Comment: Just for test try to replace back tick string with classic `var url = geoserverUrl + '/wfs?service=...`

Answer (score 0):

You must have encountered CORS errors (error 403,404).
Please press CTRL+SHIFT+I and show the errors in the console.
If they are CORS errors then follow the following link and learn how to fix them
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1qrikPfLBFs&t=24s